# Glass cooktop stove with scratches on it

Tags: kitchens, stove

Yesterday my exhaust hood broke (short circuit, I guess) and all of the plastic melted on top of the stove... I got it cleaned and the exhaust hood removed.

Now my stove has scratches on the glass (caused by heating or cleaning, I don't know) and I was wondering if it has to be replaced entirely or they wouldn't cause any problems when the stove is being used.

[Here's an image of the scratches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rGCb.jpg)

Comment: Wow. I can't even imagine what carved out hard glass like that. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 1):

The photo looks like the glass is pitted rather than scratched.  They don't look to be very deep but it could have weakened the glass enough for it to crack when you turn the heat on.  The worst thing that will happen when you turn on the heat is the glass will crack.  In that case you will need to replace the glass for sure. Just be careful that when you are cleaning the stove top you don't cut yourself if the pits are sharp.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jack of all trades is right, it looks like it’s pitted. However, if it part of your exhaust hood that is still melted on the glass, Jenn-Air, (my glass top stove company,) says to use, “a single blade razor blade at a 30 degree angle to remove burned on spots.”

Then, “use a fine polishing powers such as Bon Ami, or commercial ceramic cleaner such as Elmo Cooktop Cleaning Creme (Part No. 20000001).”

If scrubbing is necessary, they recommend “a plastic scrubber, such as Tuffy.”

Also, they recommend the paste (creme) stay on the glass for 30 - 40 minutes for really tough spots.